# How to get a precision stable 4.01v output?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

[image]

I have an unstable power supply voltage between 4.925v to 5.212 DC. How to get a precision stable 4.01v output?

Comment: The output load current is less than 50mA

Comment: What drives the need for such a voltage? Why not 4V?

Comment: Do you want surface mount or through-hole?  What tolerance output?

Comment: With only a 0.9V difference between in and out I'd be tempted to boost input voltage first and then sort out a regulator.

Comment: @Peter 4V is ok, as long as it is stable.

Comment: @AngeloQ surface mount, tolerance <10%.

Comment: @puby, OK 10% is nowhere near 'precision', and implies 4.01V isn't really a requirement.  Your specific voltage request made me think you required very high accuracy, e.g. 0.5% or better.  There are plenty of LDOs that will do, fixed and adjustable.  I answered with a link to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like [this](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/ZRT040GC1TA/ZRT040GC1CT-ND/190772) which is very simple with 1% accuracy, but that's better suited as a voltage reference so you might prefer an LDO.  There are many low current adjustable LDO options available.  [Here](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MIC5377YC5-TR/576-3358-1-ND/1980911) is a 2% accuracy LDO which you would need to use a couple of resistors to set the output voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what accuracy you want and the amount of power you want, a precision reference at a common 4.096V can be used to get a few mA at a voltage as precise as a couple of ppm. There are a few such ICs around which are typically used to set reference voltages for ADCs or DACs (hence the weird power-of-2 voltage)

For a power supply situation (where you need more than a couple of mA) you can use LDO regulators (which have a drop out voltage of only 300mV or so) such as the TPS7A85 or similar. These will give you typical accuracies of 1% or so.

Given your comment of 10% tolerance, pretty much any LDO you can find will do the job. There are many fixed voltage versions, probably around 4V or so, or adjustable versions which will be as accurate as the resistors you use. An adjustable LDO using 1% or 0.5% tolerance resistors to set the value will easily give you the desired tolerance and stability.